# FileUpload tag is not rendered in browser

Tags: file-upload, primefaces

I am migrating the primefaces version from 4.0.RC1 to 6.2, and the fileupload tag no longer appears on the form

my web.xml part

```
<filter>
<filter-name>PrimeFaces FileUpload Filter</filter-name>
<filter-class>org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter</filter-class>
</filter> 
<filter-mapping>
<filter-name>PrimeFaces FileUpload Filter</filter-name>
<servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
</filter-mapping>
```

my test.xhtml part

```
<h:form prependId="false" id="form1" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<p:outputLabel value="Arquivo: " for="fileUpload" />
<p:fileUpload id="fileUpload" fileUploadListener="#{CtPessoaSB.handleFileUpload}" label="Escolher" uploadLabel="Enviar" cancelLabel="Cancelar" />
</h:form>
```

Comment: I evolved a little bit. Both in version 4.0.RC1 and in version 6.2 of primefaces, I had to create a FileUploadRenderer.class for the component to appear. 
But now the fileupload component has three buttons (choose, upload, cancel) and the upload and cancel buttons are always disabled. The following error appears in the browser log: Uncaught TypeError browser log: Can not read property 'getContext' of undefined

Comment: You should not have had to create your own Renderer.  Something else is wrong with your setup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by upgrading the jsf version to 2.2.
Below the pom.xml part

```
<dependency>
<groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
<artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
<version>1.3</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>commons-io</groupId>
<artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
<version>2.6</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.faces</groupId>
<artifactId>jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec</artifactId>
<version>2.2.14</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
<artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
<version>6.2</version>
</dependency>
```